# Start hyperledger composer with previously imported admin card

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have problems with imported admin card for BNA.
First session, everything is ok, then I deploy BNA on local HLF:

```
 - ./startFabric.sh
 - ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
 - composer network install -a test-bna@0.0.1 -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
 - composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n test-bna -V 0.0.1 -A admin -S adminpw # create an admin card for test-bna BNA.
 - composer card import -f ./admin@test-bna.card # card successfully imported
 - composer network ping -c admin@test-bna ---> ok!
```

Second session: I can not reuse an already imported card to start the test-bna BNA,
    `composer network start` creates a new card file and results in an error. I can see admin@test-bna card in "composer card list" but I can not use it!

Comment: Could you please post the error message you're receiving from playground?

Answer (score 0):

Playground stores data in the browsers cache and deleting this solved this issue for me. If that does not work, here are a couple of other possible solutions to try out:

[Hyperledger Composer : No business network has been specified for this connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599375/hyperledger-composer-no-business-network-has-been-specified-for-this-connection)